# Convert Zulu time in a file to format --> 2020.08.17 15:53

Tags: linux, bash

I have to convert Zulu time in a file to format --> 2020.08.17 15:53. Looks like I am close but unable to crack it.

Data File

```
[naveen@oc0663726888 BigFix_API]$ cat test_bkp.csv 
2020-08-17T15:53:31Z;Networking.NET-RUN;Sun;1.0;null;BFI Client
2019-01-25T10:57:22Z;OpenSSL;OpenSSL Project;1.0;null;BFI Client
2020-08-17T15:53:31Z;OpenSSL;OpenSSL Project;1.0;null;BFI Client
2019-01-25T10:57:22Z;Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server;RED HAT;6.9;null;BFI Client
2020-08-17T15:53:31Z;Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server;RED HAT;7.4;null;BFI Client
2020-08-17T15:57:31Z;Networking.NET-RUN;Sun;1.0;null;BFI Client
2020-08-17T15:57:31Z;OpenSSL;OpenSSL Project;1.0;null;BFI Client
2020-08-17T15:40:37Z;Networking.NET-RUN;Sun;1.0;null;BFI Client
2020-08-17T15:57:31Z;Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server;RED HAT;7.4;null;BFI Client
```

Example working command

```
date -u +%Y.%m.%d" "%H:%M -d "2020-08-17T15:53:31Z"
```

Failure Mode

```
[naveen@oc0663726888 BigFix_API]$ awk ' { A=$1";"$2;system("date -u +%Y.%m.%d\" \"%H:%M -d \""A"\"");} ' test_bkp.csv
date: invalid date ‘2020-08-17T15:53:31Z;Networking.NET-RUN;Sun;1.0;null;BFI;Client\r’
date: invalid date ‘2019-01-25T10:57:22Z;OpenSSL;OpenSSL;Project;1.0;null;BFI’
date: invalid date ‘2020-08-17T15:53:31Z;OpenSSL;OpenSSL;Project;1.0;null;BFI’
date: invalid date ‘2019-01-25T10:57:22Z;Red;Hat’
date: invalid date ‘2020-08-17T15:53:31Z;Red;Hat’
date: invalid date ‘2020-08-17T15:57:31Z;Networking.NET-RUN;Sun;1.0;null;BFI;Client\r’
date: invalid date ‘2020-08-17T15:57:31Z;OpenSSL;OpenSSL;Project;1.0;null;BFI’
date: invalid date ‘2020-08-17T15:40:37Z;Networking.NET-RUN;Sun;1.0;null;BFI;Client\r’
date: invalid date ‘2020-08-17T15:57:31Z;Red;Hat’
```

Comment: Is your requirement to only use `bash` and `date`? Or can you use python, perl, etc.?

Comment: Hi Kevin, it's good to have in bash else need to run multiple cron jobs. If not bash then perl can also help. Thanks.

Comment: Also: see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/107750/how-to-parse-iso8601-dates-with-linux-date-command

Comment: able to figure out using below command, thanks for your support.

awk -F ';' '{printf("%s;%s;%s;%s;%s;%s;$s;",$1,$2,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8);system("date -u -d "$3" +%Y.%m.%d\" \"%R");}' test.csv > test2.csv

Comment: @user14129025 In what way does using perl/python/etc. prevent you from using cron?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the idea is that one could reformat using `date` (otherwise, as Cyrus noted, just strip the unneeded characters), here is one approach:

```
awk -F';' -v OFS=';' ' $1 { cmd="date -u +\"%Y.%m.%d %H:%M\" -d "$1; while (( cmd | getline $1) > 0) {print;} close(cmd);}' test_bkp.csv
```

Explanation

```
-F';' -- field separator for parsing
OFS=';' -- output field separator
$1 -- ensures there is a line to process (i.e., blank lines skipped)
cmd=... -- set the command to execute
while (( ... )) -- use subshell to read line; the first field is re-assigned
print -- outputs the line (with the substituted first field)
close(cmd) -- close the command to avoid file handle issues
```

Output

```
2020.08.17 15:53;L1;Networking.NET-RUN;Sun;1.0;null;BFI Client
2019.01.25 10:57;L2;OpenSSL;OpenSSL Project;1.0;null;BFI Client
2020.08.17 15:53;L3;OpenSSL;OpenSSL Project;1.0;null;BFI Client
2019.01.25 10:57;L4;Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server;RED HAT;6.9;null;BFI Client
2020.08.17 15:53;L5;Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server;RED HAT;7.4;null;BFI Client
2020.08.17 15:57;L6;Networking.NET-RUN;Sun;1.0;null;BFI Client
2020.08.17 15:57;L7;OpenSSL;OpenSSL Project;1.0;null;BFI Client
2020.08.17 15:40;L8;Networking.NET-RUN;Sun;1.0;null;BFI Client
2020.08.17 15:57;L9;Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server;RED HAT;7.4;null;BFI Client
```

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions:

- all input lines start with a date that needs to be modified
- no need to convert to a different timezone (eg, from zulu to local time)
- we can truncate the seconds (ie, no need to round the seconds up/down to the nearest minute)

The date/times (in the file) appear to already be in the desired format except for a bit of editing ...

- replace `-` (hyphen) with `.` (period)
- replace `T` with   (space)
- remove the seconds/Z

... so no need to call `date` to reformat the date/times.

Some sample data:

```
$ cat zulu.dat
2020-08-17T15:53:31Z;Networking.NET-RUN;Sun;1.0;null;BFI Client
2019-01-25T10:57:22Z;OpenSSL;OpenSSL Project;1.0;null;BFI Client
2020-08-17T15:53:31Z;OpenSSL;OpenSSL Project;1.0;null;BFI Client
2019-01-25T10:57:22Z;Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server;RED HAT;6.9;null;BFI Client
2020-08-17T15:53:31Z;Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server;RED HAT;7.4;null;BFI Client
```

One `awk` solution:

```
awk -F";" '                       # input field separator = ";"
BEGIN {OFS=";"}                   # output field separator = ";"
      {gsub(/-/,".",$1)           # replace "-" with "." in field 1
       gsub(/T/," ",$1)           # replace "T" with " " (space) in field 1
       $1=substr($1,1,16)         # strip off ":<sec>Z" and re-assign to field #1
       print                      # print our newly formatted line
      }
' zulu.dat
```

The above generates the following from the sample file:

```
2020.08.17 15:53;Networking.NET-RUN;Sun;1.0;null;BFI Client
2019.01.25 10:57;OpenSSL;OpenSSL Project;1.0;null;BFI Client
2020.08.17 15:53;OpenSSL;OpenSSL Project;1.0;null;BFI Client
2019.01.25 10:57;Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server;RED HAT;6.9;null;BFI Client
2020.08.17 15:53;Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server;RED HAT;7.4;null;BFI Client
```